# Downgrade Rights with Windows Server 2019 Standard RETAIL (FFP) Licensed edition

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2019, microsoft, downgrade

According to the actual RETAIL Full-Package Product (FPP) licensing EULA both online and on disk (C:\Windows\System32\License.rtf) from recent installs I have (Activated and Licensed) of Windows Server 2019 Standard Retail channel purchase...

Downgrade Rights are Granted and allowed.

See Section 5.b Additional Licensing Provisions | Downgrade Rights

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/UseTerms/Retail/WindowsServer2019/DatacenterAndStandard/Useterms_Retail_WindowsServer2019_DatacenterAndStandard_English.htm

But every other interpretation and QnA on the web seems to think Retail licenses do NOT allow Downgrade Rights??

This is a total contradiction to what is stated in all the License.rtf shipped as part of the final installed product.

Even Microsofts latest Licensing Brief from Sept 2020 titled "Downgrade rights for Microsoft Commercial Licensing, OEM, and full-package product licenses" states:

FPP Microsoft Software License Terms
Server Software:
Some server products offer downgrade rights.
Please refer to the FPP license terms for complete details.

Am i misinterpreting the legal license phrasing?

Is Microsoft distributing/installing the *wrong* RETAIL license.rtf file with WS2019 Std media (ISO from Microosft.com)

Comment: Probably simpler to contact Microsoft. On an anecdotal note, I've never heard of Microsoft taking action for downgrading.

Comment: Downgrading retail is always a headache, but more to get the media. Usually you just can, but you need to provide the media/keys, which can be harder if you dont have a open license to download them as you got a retail media.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't produce different media or ISO installers for their Server Edition products. its all the same bits in the end. Its only the 128bit activation KEYS that makes the difference in the end.. Microsoft provides all their ISO installers for Server 2008/2012/2016/2019/2022 available on their web site... so the only thing that matters is the EULA from the sales channel. so in this case for me its RETAIL (FPP) license.. just like i bought it form the Microsoft Online Store directly.

Comment: ISO or not, my point was more you need to find a key to use on that downgraded OS,  unlike open licence where you get access to downgrade key and download directly.

Comment: @HestonHoltmann that's not correct, the only license that's valid is the license that came shipped with the program itself. It's not the customers fault when Microsoft is being lazy. Every lawyer in every civilized country will agree to that. OP should demand that his right for downgrading becomes fulfilled by Microsoft or otherwise call a lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

From:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/UseTerms/Retail/WindowsServer2019/DatacenterAndStandard/Useterms_Retail_WindowsServer2019_DatacenterAndStandard_English.htm

**^^ NOTICE its states "RETAIL" in the link.**
This link contains also the EXACT same text that is installed on Windows Server 2019 Std edition in the C:\Windows\System32\License.RTF file AFTER you activate and apply a purchased RETAIL license KEY.

So *where* does everyone get the miss-information that you Can't apply Downgrade rights to Retail licenses??

Last updated April 2018

MICROSOFT SOFTWARE LICENSE TERMS
MICROSOFT WINDOWS SERVER

1. License Model Overview.
2. Definitions
3. How to License Server Software
4. Windows Server Client Access Licenses (CALs)
5. Additional Licensing Provisions

**5b. Downgrade Rights.**

Instead of creating, storing, and using the software, for each permitted instance, **you may create, store, and use an earlier version of the following editions of the software for so long as Microsoft provides support for that earlier version as set forth in (aka.ms/windowslifecycle):**

```
     **For Windows Server Standard**
```

·        Windows Server Standard

·        Windows Server Essentials

·        Windows Server Foundation

·        Windows Server Enterprise

·        Windows Web Server

·        Windows HPC Server Operating System

```
     **For Windows Server Datacenter**
```

·        Windows Server Datacenter

·        Windows Server Standard

·        Windows Server Essentials

·        Windows Server Foundation

·        Windows Server Enterprise

·        Windows Web Server

·        Windows HPC Server Operating System

This agreement applies to your use of the earlier versions of the editions listed above. For the avoidance of doubt, by electing this downgrade option: (i) you will not have the right to create, store, or use a greater number of instances of the software than are permitted under this agreement, and (ii) you will need to acquire licenses for all cores in the physical server in accordance with Section 3 of this agreement. If the earlier version includes different components not covered in this agreement, the terms that are associated with those components in the earlier version of these editions apply to your use of them. Neither the manufacturer or installer, nor Microsoft is obligated to supply earlier versions or other editions to you. At any time, you may replace an earlier version or edition with this version and edition of the software.

Comment: This license aggreement is not valid. Anybody can download the install program and give it to a third person. The only license agreement which is valid is the license agreement which the installer has agreed to while installing the software onto a conputer.

Comment: That is a good point.. but is also easy to verify by starting the install on a VM from any Server Edition ISO obtained from Microsoft. I wonder if there is a way to have the license manager script on a running Server OS spit out the EULA? will have to check.